# Finder quit unexpectedly

Tags: macos, finder

I've got an issue where Finder quits at startup and then every 2-5 seconds after.

Problem details and system config are as follows:

```
Process:         Finder [3103]
Path:            /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
Identifier:      Finder
Version:         ???
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [184]
Responsible:     Finder [3103]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-09-25 13:12:30.718 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  D879BEB2-6DB1-8267-220C-B8ABDE8A8D18


Crashed Thread:  0

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

kernel messages:
-0 sec              CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=3110[GoogleSoftwareUp] final status 0x0, allowing (remove VALID) page

VM Regions Near 0x7fae4970ed70 (cr2):
    VM_ALLOCATE            000000010dd77000-000000010dd78000 [    4K] rw-/rwx SM=ALI  
--> 
    STACK GUARD            00007fff4e48b000-00007fff51c8b000 [ 56.0M] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x00007fff603e4028 _dyld_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000000000000000d  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x00007fff5248ad38
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff603e4028  rfl: 0x0000000000000201  cr2: 0x00007fae4970ed70

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x020000f4
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
    0x7fff603e3000 -     0x7fff60416817  dyld (???) <7AD43B9B-5CEA-3C7E-9836-A06909F9CA56> /usr/lib/dyld

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 189
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=288K resident=228K(79%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=60K(21%)
Writable regions: Total=8488K written=0K(0%) resident=12K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=8476K(100%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                           8K
VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)               48K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
__DATA                              252K
__LINKEDIT                           80K
__TEXT                              208K
mapped file                        6104K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                              70.5M
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     70.5M


Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B02, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.7f3 14616, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Home VPN, PPP (PPTP)
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD512E, 500.28 GB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Is there anyway of fixing this? Ideally I'd like to not have to reinstall my OS!  I've already repaired permissions and disk from the command+R startup screen

Having uninstalled Chrome I'm now seeing this - pretty much the same error message but without mention to Google

```
Process:         Finder [14398]
Path:            /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
Identifier:      Finder
Version:         ???
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [174]
Responsible:     Finder [14398]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-09-25 13:43:04.041 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  D879BEB2-6DB1-8267-220C-B8ABDE8A8D18


Crashed Thread:  0

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

kernel messages:

VM Regions Near 0x7fdbc060dd60 (cr2):
    VM_ALLOCATE            00000001095be000-00000001095bf000 [    4K] rw-/rwx SM=ALI  
--> 
    STACK GUARD            00007fff52c44000-00007fff56444000 [ 56.0M] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x00007fff62407028 _dyld_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000000000000000d  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x00007fff56c43d38
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff62407028  rfl: 0x0000000000000201  cr2: 0x00007fdbc060dd60

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x020000f4
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
    0x7fff62406000 -     0x7fff62439817  dyld (???) <7AD43B9B-5CEA-3C7E-9836-A06909F9CA56> /usr/lib/dyld

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 215
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=288K resident=216K(75%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=72K(25%)
Writable regions: Total=8488K written=0K(0%) resident=12K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=8476K(100%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                           8K
VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)               48K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
__DATA                              252K
__LINKEDIT                           80K
__TEXT                              208K
mapped file                        6104K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                              70.5M
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     70.5M


Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B02, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.7f3 14616, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Home VPN, PPP (PPTP)
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD512E, 500.28 GB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Comment: Looks like Google software update bug. Could You try to disable it by followin this post: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/77249/macbook-pro-keeps-freezing-could-google-update-be-the-cause ?

Comment: Hm..these commands didn't work for me as I didn't have the plist entry there.  Have uninstalled chrome and google updater and still getting a finder crash - new error log posted.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after upgrading to Sierra 10.12.4. I tried various suggestions including deleting Finder preferences and Sidebar preferences without success. However installing the 'Combo Update' for Sierra 10.12.4 from Terminal  using the instructions found at http://luo.ma/geek/terminal-combo worked for me. The only things I needed to change in the shell-script provided there were the Combo Update version link and also changed '-gt' to '-ge' so it would run when the version number was the same as that already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove GoogleSoftwareUpdate! It's evil on your machine.

Download the unofficial uninstalled [here](http://wireload.net/products/guu-google-update-uninstaller/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I've repaired permissions and the disk already.  Will add that info to the question.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to change my question.

Comment: Have done this, and uninstalled chrome - issue still happening, will post new error

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Docker, I saw a thread that implicates this with Finder crashes:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1658289

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have Docker - I do believe that this started happening after a software update, so I imagine the issue is with another piece of software which is not compatible - but I've no idea which bit of software that is!

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the Google Chrome has not left a bitter taste in your VM (Virtual Memory).

> While active memory contents are maintained in memory, the system also
>   keeps some recently used but inactive processes and data there in
>   order to quickly revive them, if needed.

The Terminal command would be:

```
sudo purge
```

Be aware that [purging can have side effects](http://www.cnet.com/news/the-necessity-of-regular-use-of-the-purge-command-in-os-x/).

If above failed:

Run in Safe mode to verify if problem exists.

If problem continues use the Repair/Test your hardware.

Use Disk Utility repair.

Next run the Apple Hardware Test.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem recently on a mid-2010 MacBook Pro 15" (model 6,2).  I'm not entirely sure how I fixed it, but here was my process (forgive me for not having references to all the other threads I consulted readily available):

I installed and ran Onyx, which indicated that I needed to repair my drive, which I did by booting with the Option key held down.  (Something like that.  The point is you need to run Disk Utility without booting from that drive, and I believe doing this causes you to boot into the recovery partition or something like that, but I'm a little fuzzy on the details.)  I both repaired the drive itself and the permissions.

Later, I noticed that I had an unfinished update of Xcode 6.1, so I removed the half-downloaded new installation.  This briefly appeared to work, but soon Finder was back to spontaneously terminating every minute or so.

I found that booting into Safe Mode caused the problem to go away (verified by opening the Activity Monitor, clicking on Finder, and checking to see if it would spontaneously terminate).  Following @awesomebing1's advice, I ran the Google Update Uninstaller, rebooted into regular mode; no joy.

(I may have done one or two other things here, but I don't think they were critical.)

I ran the Apple Hardware Test to check that it wasn't an issue with my third-party RAM or something along those lines.  (If you're not especially experienced with using the terminal, obtaining and installing AHT may be nontrivial; also, halfway decent Google-fu may be required to actually find the `.dmg` containing AHT.)  My computer passed.

I thought maybe my updating `bash` to 4.3.27 could have had something to do with this, but Homebrew is (in my experience, at least) good about not breaking things.

Flummoxed, I thought I'd need to wipe the disk, clone an old backup, and then migrate the new data onto 10.9.4 (I'm not entirely sure that this would work well).  Before trying that, I thought I'd have nothing to lose by running the 10.9.5 combo updater and then trying to update Xcode again.  Since doing those two things, everything appears to be running fine -- my current Finder process has be up for over an hour without terminating.

tl;dr: Try the 10.9.5 combo updater.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend upgrading to Yosemite. It sounds like your Finder application is in a state that it doesn't run - it could be a broken update or malware. As others pointed out Chrome and Google Software Update are unlikely the cause. To the best of my knowledge, Chrome does not interact with Finder. Google Software Update does, but only during self-updates, which on a normally running machine are quite rare. I am familiar with the Google Software Update code - it doesn't do anything special, just uses the session of the Finder to make sure that its own agent is started on that session. This is performed by executing an Apple utility in that session, not Google Software Update's code in the Finder context. If you are curious, you can learn more about OS X agents here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083.

Additionally, most of the Google Software Update code is open source. You can get the idea of what it does here: https://code.google.com/p/update-engine/
It is unfortunate that I cannot give you a better advice, but upgrading the machine is probably the safest bet of restoring the machine/Finder state.